# How do I do mongo aggregation for this particular case?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation, nosql-aggregation

I got a collection 'A'
which has documents like

```
{
 "_id": <>,
"entity_id": <>,
"user_id" <>,
created_at:<>
}
```

I need to get a certain property 'organization_name' from collection 'B' whose _id matches with "user_id" of collection 'A' documents

make finally I expect this output:

```
{
_id:<>,
organization_name:<>,
user_id:<>,
entity_id:<>
created_at:<>
}
```

initial matching criterion can be {created_at:{$gt:<>,$lt:<>}}

Comment: What have you tried using `"$lookup"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the aggregation framework with `$match`,`$lookup` and `$unwind` stages. I think something like this is what are you looking for:

```
db.a_collection_name.aggregate([
    {$match: {created_at:{$gt:<>,$lt:<>}}},
    {$lookup: {
       from:  <b_collection_name>,
       localField: "user_id",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "output"
    }},
    {$unwind: {
       path: "$output",
    }}
])
```

`$match` sets the match condition, the filter stage in operations like `find`. `$lookup` is basically a left outer join or a populate, and `$unwind` deconstructs the array obtained in the previous lookup stage. Check the official mongodb aggregation framework documentation if you want to learn more https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/. Mongodb University has a aggregation course that is very cool https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about

Comment: Yeah, I tried this one below but it is not giving me any result
[{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":startDate,"$lt":endDate}}},{"$lookup":{ "from": "people","localField":"user_id","foreignField":"_id","as":"fromPeople"}},
    {"$unwind":"$fromPeople"},{"$match":{"fromPeople.organization_type":"school"}},{"$project":{"fromPeople.organization_type":1,"fromPeople.organization":1,"user_id":1}}]

Comment: I'll surely go through the course on coming weekend.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is important or not but, are you using mongo ObjectId or string in _id?

Comment: Yes ObjectID. I made sure it wasn't just a string

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "created_at": {
        "$gte": "2021-02-01",
        "$lt": "2022-02-01"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "people",
      "localField": "user_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "fromPeople"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fromPeople"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fromPeople.organization_type": "school"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "fromPeople.organization_type": 1,
      "fromPeople.organization": 1,
      "user_id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gtb3QPhK53k)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a problem with `ObjectId`. Try this and add the `$match` and `$project` stages after `$unwind` as @YuTing suggested:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "created_at": {
        "$gte": "2021-02-01",
        "$lt": "2022-02-01"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "user_id_transform": {
        "$toObjectId": "$user_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "people",
      "localField": "user_id_transform",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "fromPeople"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fromPeople"
  }
])
```